# Let ModalView fit all its contents widgets (kivy)

Tags: python, modal-dialog, kivy, kivy-language, modal-view

What's the proper way to add a set of widgets into a ModalView in `kivy` so that the modal window fits all of its contents dynamically (without setting the height to a hard-coded pixel size)?

I have the following example script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import kivy
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App

KV = """
BoxLayout:
    ModalView:
        size_hint: 0.9, None

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'

            Label:
                text: 'Dialog Title'
                font_size: 30

            Label:
                text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
            Label:
                text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
            Label:
                text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
            Label:
                text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."

            StackLayout:
                orientation: 'rl-tb'

                Button:
                    text: "OK"
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: self.texture_size
                    padding: '8dp', '8dp'

                Button:
                    text: "Cancel"
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: self.texture_size
                    padding: '8dp', '8dp'
"""

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string( KV )


MyApp().run()
```

As the kivy langauge describes, I want a modal to appear with 90% width of the app and the height should dynamically adjust to fit all the contents of the modal.

The modal's contents should be a "title" label with a set of "body" labels below it. Below these labels should be two buttons that appear on the same line. Pretty straight-forward.

But this is what I get:

[image: widgets not appearing properly in kivy modal view]

Note that the above image shows:

1. the buttons are mostly outside the modal
2. The title label is partially ontop of the below labels (this is not how BoxLayout should work)
3. The title label is also partially outside the modal

How can I fix this script so that the contents of the modal appears as expected?

Comment: Why are you using a `ModalView` in that situation?

Comment: Is there a better way to display a dialog pop-up with a notice and confirmation buttons?

Comment: I suggest using [Popup](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.popup.html) and note the documentation says "Popup is a special widget. Don’t try to add it as a child to any other widget".

Comment: I don't like the way the Popup widget looks, which is why I wanted to use `ModalView` directly. If I change the above code from `ModalView` to `Popup`, the same issue occurs. How can I use the Popup widget in a distinct `.kv` (kivy language) file without it being a child of any other widget?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `size_hint: 0.9, None`, then you must specify the `height` of the `ModalView`. The simplest way to do that is to let the widgets do the calculations by using `minimum_height` of the children `Layouts`. Something like this:

```
<MyModal@ModalView>:
    size_hint: 0.9, None
    height: box.height
    BoxLayout:
        id: box
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.minimum_height
        padding: 5
        spacing: 5

        Label:
            text: 'Dialog Title'
            font_size: 30
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size

        Label:
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size
        Label:
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size
        Label:
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size
        Label:
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size

        StackLayout:
            orientation: 'rl-tb'
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.minimum_height

            Button:
                text: "OK"
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
                padding: '8dp', '8dp'

            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
                padding: '8dp', '8dp'
```

Note that using `minimum_height` requires that the children of that `Layout` must have well defined `heights`.

Comment: That works much better, but it's still *slightly* too small of a height. I ended-up just using `height: box.height + dp(16)` in my app, and it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can put a rule in your `kv` that describe how the `ModalView` should be built without making it a child of any widget. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#dynamic-classes). You could use a rule something like:

```
<MyModal@ModalView>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            text: 'Dialog Title'
            font_size: 30

        Label:
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        Label:
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        Label:
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        Label:
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."

        StackLayout:
            orientation: 'rl-tb'

            Button:
                text: "OK"
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
                padding: '8dp', '8dp'

            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
                padding: '8dp', '8dp'
```

Then in your python code, you create the `ModalView` like this:

```
from kivy.factory import Factory
modal_inst = Factory.MyModal()
modal_inst.open()
```

Comment: "MyModal@ModlView" is this a typo?

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately your solution has the same problem as my code when you add the `size_hint: 0.9, None` to `MyModal` See screenshot https://i.imgur.com/njP1H5s.png